# fmap fork functions

Tags: haskell

I want to compose functions in the following way:

```
compose :: (a->b->c) -> (d->a) -> (d->b) -> d -> c
compose f g h x = f (g x) (h x)
```

So that we can use it in the following way:

```
compose (==) (myReverse . myReverse) id [1..100]
```

I think it could be simplified with something like 'fmap', so that it needn't define 'compose' at all. But I failed to figure out how to do that.

Comment: What you have provided is the simplest and most readable solution. There may be other so called "dense" code solution for this, but I prefer the simple and readable code :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you import [`Control.Applicative`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html), then

```
compose f g h = f <$> g <*> h
```

So, you can write `(==) <$> (myReverse . myReverse) <*> id $ [1..100]`

`<*>` specialized to functions is equivalent to the [S-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus):

```
s f g x = f x (g x)
```

You can probably use `Control.Arrow` too:

```
compose f g h = g &&& h >>> uncurry f
test = uncurry (==) <<< (myReverse <<< myReverse) &&& id $ [1..100]
```

***Update***

I've asked `lambdabot` at `#haskell` the same question and he answered simply `liftM2`. :D

Comment: +1, nice answer. As a semi-noob I tried to get to both solutions myself, got very close but didn't make it (I missed the `<<<` for composing with `uncurry`).

Comment: Actually `<<<` is equivalent to `.`. It's the `&&&` which does the job (splits the argument) here.

Comment: I know that `<<<` is composition, but I got stuck with `uncurry (==) ((reverse . reverse) &&& id) $ [1..100]`, which in hindsight is rather stupid.

Comment: Incidentally, the `Applicative` instance on functions is the `Reader` monad, sans the `newtype` wrapper, so you can also think of `f <$> g <*> h` here as being `do { x <- g; y <- h; return (f x y) }` in a reader monad where the reader's "environment" is the shared argument to `g` and `h`.

Comment: Indeed. Is `do{g<-g; h<-h;...` considered a bad naming style btw? I use it all the time, but rarely find it used by others for some reason.

Comment: @Rotsor: Coming up with good names for things is hard, but I think haskellers have a tendency to use bad names a bit too much. Sure, it's fine to call something `f` or `x` when it could be _any_ function or value, but I think it's worth the effort to come up with a good name to aid the people reading your code. If the intermediate value is not important, it is possible that using point-free/applicative style will be better than coming up with a useless name.

Comment: @hammar I meant using the same name on the left-hand and right-hand side of `<-`, not 1-letter names. `g` was chosen by the original asker, so is definitely a good name here! :)

Comment: @Rotsor: Ah I see. In that case, I would argue that a function and it's result (or a monadic value and it's contents) are two different things and you shouldn't confuse them by giving them the same name.

Comment: @Rotsor: Shadowing names in general is considered bad style in most circumstances. In your example, if there's *really* no better name for the bound values, a more acceptable approach would be using the apostrophe-as-[prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29) style, e.g. binding `g` to `g'`. That said, since the shadowing you suggested ensures the original value won't be used again, I'd expect there to be a point-free/applicative style expression for whatever the final result is that would be clearer.

Comment: I thought about this rather as a nice trick to kill 2 birds with one stone -- bring unnecessary monadic value out of scope and avoid awk. abbrevs for the bound value. Also, having different types makes accidental mistakes non-fatal.

Comment: I use `liftA2` rather than `liftM2`, since the former is more general, and the latter is a historical accident. (`Monad` was discovered before `Applicative`.)